# latex R code with %*%

Tags: listings, r

I'm using latex with `lstlisting` to format my R code. Some of my code uses matrix arithmetic, including `%*%`. Unfortunately this causes errors when compiling.

There is an example of what I would like to do...

```
\begin{lstlisting}
solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: What errors? No problem here compiling this when pasted into a [MWE](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)...

Comment: Thanks Werner, your comment lead me toward the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I'm not smart. I had copy pasted a `\lstset` from an example, and it included:

```
\lstset{ 
 ...snip...
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
 ...snip...
}
```

which obviously (in hindsight) states that `%*` gets interpreted as the start of latex code (or something).

Deleting that line solved the issue.

Comment: Exactly, the text between `%*` and the first `*` afterwards will be interpreted as `TeX`, instead of text. One can easily change these signs to fit his needs.